# Advanced Editor SSPIS: Can I set to ignore truncation error on many columns at once, instead of one by one?

Tags: ssis

Screenshot from my SSIS:
[image: Screenshot from my SSIS]

As you can see on the image above, I have a CSV with multiple columns. Sadly most of them get truncated and I need to set each of them to ignore the error. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

I've Googled extensively but this questions seems to remain unanswered. Ctrl+A doesn't work, holding CTRL, and clicking neither. There isn't any button to do it.
I have like 100 columns and I refuse to acknowledge that I need to do it manually but clicking around or Googling doesn't work. Stack Overflow also nothing. I'm not asking for anything on a silver platter, I'd appreciate just pointing me to something I have been blind to.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to resolve it on my own. Flat File source editor->Error output -> Truncation column, ctrl+mouseclick.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]